# Wordpress URL rewrite custom taxonomy using add_rewrite_rule() or generate_rewrite_rules()

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to get my head around amending some URL's for a website I have created. After reading two (very informative) answers ([1](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39500/how-to-create-a-permalink-structure-with-custom-taxonomies-and-custom-post-types), [2](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5413/need-help-with-add-rewrite-rule)) but I'm still a little unsure how to approach creating a URL that shows a custom post type in the hierachy of it's categories (created by custom taxonomies).

From my reading, I gather that `add_rewrite_rule` or `generate_rewrite_rules` seem to be the best options to use, but I cannot seem to get it functional... like... at all! **Here is the URL structure I have currently**:

```
Base        = http://domain.com/bands
Category    = http://domain.com/band-type/acoustic-duos
Single Post = http://domain.com/bands/duo-1
```

And **here is what I am looking to achieve**:

```
Base        = http://domain.com/bands
Category    = http://domain.com/bands/acoustic-duos
Single Post = http://domain.com/bands/acoustic-duos/duo-1
```

In the scenario above, **`bands` is the custom-post-type**, whilst **`band-type` is the custom-taxonomy** I have created for 'bands'.

From using @jan-fabry Rewrite Analyzer plugin, I can see the custom taxonomy pattern is: `band-type/([^/]+)/?$` for the first argument for `add_rewrite_rule()` but I don't know how Wordpress references custom taxonomies in the index.php URL variable, used for the `$redirect` argument (e.g. `index.php?tax=bands`)... so unsurprisingly the following code (placed within `functions.php`) did not work at all:

```php
wp_reset_query();
function sheixt_init()
{
add_rewrite_rule(
    'band-type/([^/]+)/?',
    'index.php?cat=&band-type=$matches[1]',
    'top' );
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'sheixt_query_vars' );
function sheixt_query_vars( $query_vars )
{
    $query_vars[] = 'band-type';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

I still feel I'm not grasping how this works (at all!) and reading the codex is confusing me further so I'm not sure how to approach using `generate_rewrite_rules()`.

Lastly, I'm wondering if I'm fooling foul of a permalink conflict, as I want the custom-taxonomy (band-type) to use the custom-post-type's slug ('bands') as the baseline for the URL.

Please can you point me in the right direction, I can provide more information if necessary. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This can all be done with your .htaccess file. This assumes the .htacces file is in your root directory and that wordpress is installed in the root directory and not a subfolder. If you installed wordpress in a subfolder change the RewriteBase to:

```
RewriteBase http://domain.com/subfolder/
```

Where subfolder is the subdirectory where you installed wordpress. For all else use the code below where the wordpress install is in the root directory.

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^band-type/acoustic-duos/(.*)$ bands/acoustic-duos/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^bands/(.*)$ bands/acoustic-duos/$1 [QSA,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Be careful when editing the .htaccess file. Make sure to save a backup of your current .htaccess before editing using the code above. I believe the first RewriteRule should work. the second RewriteRule may cause a redirect loop or your site to crash because we are redirecting two urls:

```
/bands/duo-1 
/band-type/acoustic-duos
```

to have a new base of:

```
/bands/acoustic-duos
```