# Custom taxonomy slug issues

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I have a strange issue about my custom taxonomy. I want to rewrite the slug. But when I try to display the taxonomies with the slug I get only the taxonomy name as slug and not with the rewrite slug.

So my taxonomy called `models-cat` and what I want is. When I display the taxonomies I wan't my rewrite slug before the taxonomy name for example `/rewrite/taxonomy`.

Does someone has any idea?

Comment: If you're using a apache webserver, edit the `.htaccess` file in the wordpress root directory to add URL rewrite rules. See this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25047442/wordpress-url-rewrite-custom-taxonomy-using-add-rewrite-rule-or-generate-rewri).

Comment: @mch Thanks for your answer but I don't like it to do it the hardcode way..

Answer (score 0):

Rewrites of the taxonomy slug can be defined in the `register_taxonomy` function.

```
$taxonomy_name = 'models-cat';
$taxonomy_post_type = 'post';

register_taxonomy($taxonomy_name, $taxonomy_post_type, array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => 'Cats',
        'singular_name' => 'Cat',
        'search_items' => 'Search Cats',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Cat',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Cat',
    ),
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'model/cat', 'with_front' => false)
));
```

Source: [The Right Way to do WordPress Custom Taxonomy Rewrites](https://cnpagency.com/blog/the-right-way-to-do-wordpress-custom-taxonomy-rewrites/)